# Sticky Footer CSS Problems

Tags: css, height, footer

I have been able to design my layout so that it has 2 columns and a width of 100%, you can see that [here](http://www.prashantraju.com/test/).

Now I'm trying to implement a sticky footer (100%) height with this layout which also has the background in the right hand column flow down the footer and also with the border I have in the left hand column.

Is there a way to do this with my current layout or it would great if anyone could suggest an alternative to the way I'm currently doing it!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [Sticky Footer 2009](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/). This has been  discussed [multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sticky+footer) on SO as well.

Comment: ChssPly76,

I have got that working however I have no idea on making the columns flow down as well?

Comment: Your col2 seems to have fixed width, right? Use a right-aligned background image.

Comment: ChssPly76,

Yes it does however even after implementing the sticky footer (using your link) my main body does flow all the way down to the footer. See here http://www.prashantraju.com/test/index_fix.html. Any tips on how to get that working?

Comment: Meant to say doesn't not does.

Comment: Your HTML layout is wrong. `clearfix` needs to be applied to the "main" div right within `wrapper`, and that "main" div should be the only one within. You have both `header` and `colmask`. Background image I've mentioned above should be applied to `wrapper` div as well.

Comment: ChssPly76,
Think i got it!!!
http://www.prashantraju.com/test/index_fix.html
Thanks for your help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I would add a CSS class to the DIV containing the columns and style that.  To get close, I had to add the following to your CSS file:

```
body
{
 height: 100%;
}

.footer
{
 position: absolute;
 top: 90%;
 left: 0;
 height: 10%;
}
```